# How do I generate test cases for pictures using the RGBA constructor in the Gloss library?

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am trying to write some test cases using HUnit in Haskell for a function using the Gloss Graphics library.

The function:

```
makePicture :: Color -> Picture
makePicture c = Color c $ Circle 80
```

If I display a call to this function with argument "black" in a console you see something like:

```
Color (RGBA 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0) (Circle 80.0)
```

Which has the type of a Picture. My question is how do I properly write a test case for something like this?

The problem occurs if I try to write a test like:

```
test = TestCase $ assertEqual "makePicture" (Color (RGBA 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0) (Circle 80.0)) (makePicture black)
```

It can't compile, because it says the following:

```
error: Data constructor not in scope: RGBA
```

Anyone have any ideas how I can write a test case for my function?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you are getting the `RGBA` constructor, but looking at the haddocks there is no such constructor for a `Color`.  You probably want the [`makeColor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.10.2.5/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Data-Color.html#t:Color) function:

```
makeColor :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Color
```

EDIT: And yes, user24...38 is right there exists an `RGBA` but in the version of Gloss I'm looking at it is part of an `Internal` module and not exported elsewhere.  As a general rule, external users should not leverage `Internal` modules since the API might change or the interface can be somehow unsafe (ex: not maintaining invariants).

Comment: [There is such a constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-rendering-1.10.3.5/docs/src/Graphics-Gloss-Internals-Data-Color.html#Color), it is defined in a dependency of gloss, but `Color` is abstract and the constructor is not exported. Effectively, 'there is no such constructor' is a true statement, but perhaps this pedantic distinction would be useful to the understanding for someone.